# How to get the uploaded file's size when using lightning-file-upload?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-controller, fileupload, lightning-file-upload

I've tried the following but it returns 'undefined.

```js
event.detail.files[0].size
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way from `lightning-file-upload` itself. This is all from the [lightning-file-upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation) docs.

One reason it doesn't provide the size is that it handles the file size limit automatically (and displays it automatically on upload as well)

[image]

> File Upload Limits
>
> By default, you can upload up to 10 files
> simultaneously unless your Salesforce admin has changed that limit.
> The org limit for the number of files simultaneously uploaded is a
> maximum of 25 files and a minimum of 1 file. The maximum file size you
> can upload is 2 GB. In Experience Builder sites, the file size limits
> and types allowed follow the settings determined by site file
> moderation.

It terms of what you tried (ex. `event.detail.files[0]`), it describes the attributes returned in the only event (`uploadFinished`):

> event.detail.files **returns a list of uploaded files with the
> attributes name and documentId**. If a guest user performed the file
> upload, the documentId is not returned.
>
> - name: The file name in the format filename.extension, for example,
>   account.jpg.
> - documentId: The ContentDocument Id in the format
>   069XXXXXXXXXXXX.

As you can see, there's no `size` attribute for you to get the file size through this component. You'd have to get the size outside of this standard component (apex method using `documentId`). You can take the `documentId` and get the `ContentSize` from [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm).